# A better way to get all y values on hover in a multiline chart d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dry

In my [**block**](https://bl.ocks.org/LemoNode/a9dc1a454fdc80ff2a738a9990935e9d) **(Updated)** here I've added a `d3.bisector` to get all y values on hover, what I'm wondering now is if there is a better way to get all values without having to append a new text element to the `focus` variable for each value and later select them all in the `mouseover` function.

I'm thinking that adding `.data(cities)` to the `focus` variable and later referincing the data in `.text(function(d) {return d.values})` somehow is a good way to go about it.

Am I on the right track or is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before addressing your question: you wrote...

```
let keys = data.columns.slice(1, 5); // This works for some reason...
```

... for a snippet that you know it should be:

```
let keys = data.columns.slice(1, 4);
//just 3 cities here ------------^
```

And said *"This works for some reason"*. The explanation is simple, you already have an element with a class `city`:

```
g.append("g").attr("class", "city");
```

Therefore, when you do this:

```
var city = g.selectAll(".city")
    .data(cities);
```

You are binding the first data object to a group that you never use. So, just change those class names, and do `slice(1, 4)`, which is the correct one.

Back to your question:

Yes, you can simplify that code a lot, using an enter selection:

```
var labels = focus.selectAll(null)
    .data(copy)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "lineHoverText")
    .attr("font-size", 11)
    .attr("x", 10)
    .attr("dy", function(_, i) {
        return 1 + i * 2 + "em"
    });
```

As you can see, I'm using `copy`, which is only an array with the three strings, and not `cities`, which is a big array full of data.

And then:

```
labels.attr("transform", "translate(" + (x(d.date) + 10) + "," + height / 2.5 + ")")
    .text(function(e) {
        return e + " " + formatMetric(d[e + METRIC])
    });
```

Here is your bl.ocks with that change: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/dc6abcbd29a6496090467fbcf230e760/9ed42bcbc73276b41b7e66abfbc111b1bf09c72a

Also, consider changing the `y` position of each label: the way they are right now you cannot know what line each label represents.

Comment: Thank you so much for the `data.columns.slice(1, 5);`  explanation, was driving me crazy.

Comment: @RobertAndersson no worries. Here is an advice: as the code in your question is a **working** code, consider asking at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) next time. Over there the answers are normally way more elaborate and complete than here - but that community is for **working code** only!

Comment: Ah, had no idea  about that site, will go there next time, cheers!